# How do I launch the Android emulator from the command line?

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, console, console-application

I'm on Mac, working on Android development from the terminal.  I have successfully created the [HelloWorld](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) project and now I'm trying to run it from the command line in the Android emulator.  Which command runs the emulator for my HelloWorld project?

I already have the Android tools and platform-tools in my PATH.

**Edit:**

How do I tell the emulator to run my HelloWorld project from the command line?  I've already built the project with ant.

Comment: Relevant docs: create with [`avdmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager) and launch with [`emulator`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline).

Answer (score 411, accepted):

I assume that you have built your project and just need to launch it, but you don't have any AVDs created and have to use command line for all the actions. You have to do the following.

1. Create a new virtual device (AVD) for the platform you need. If you have to use command line for creating your AVD, you can call `android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID>` where targetID is the API level you need. If you can use GUI, just type in `android avd` and it will launch the manager, where you can do the same. You can read more about [AVD management through GUI](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html) and [through command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).
2. Run the AVD either by using command `emulator -avd <name>` or through previously launched GUI. Wait until the emulator fully loads, it takes some time. You can read about [additional options here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#startup-options).
3. Now you have to install the application to your AVD. Usually during development you just use the same Ant script you used to build the project, just select `install` target. However, you can install the application manually using command `adb install <path-to-your-APK>`.
4. Now switch to emulator and launch your application like on any normal device, through the launcher. Or, as an alternative, you can use the following command: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <package>/<activity class>`. For example: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.sample.helloworld/org.sample.helloworld.HelloWorld`. As a commenter suggested, you can also replace `org.sample.helloworld.HelloWorld` in the line above with just `.HelloWorld`, and it will work too.

Comment: Your 4 points list is what I'm looking for.  When I run `adb install <path-to-your-APK>`, I get `error: device not found`.  If I run the emulator in one shell and the adb install command in another, I get `error: device offline`.  How do I set an emulated virtual device?

Comment: OK, brought back info from the previous version of the answer. :) If you get the message that device is offline, I think that you just haven't let the system load. It is useless to try sending commands to the emulator when it shows Android logo, you have to wait until it shows you the lockscreen. And you are right that you have to use another shell instance to send commands to your device. By the way, you may check devices' current status by using `adb devices` command.

Comment: Minor shortcut: "adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.sample.helloworld/.HelloWorld" also works.

Comment: @ThomasW Thanks, I've added this info to the answer.

Comment: Would it also be a good idea to call `adb wait-for-device` after starting the emulator?

Comment: @L2G If you run this as a script, then yes, you can do that. When I wrote the answer, I assumed you do everything by hand, in which case, of course, you can wait yourself.

Comment: Incredible, after reading the whole google android sdk site, these 4 points should be in every newbee manual at the 2nd page.

Comment: restart adb-server by: `adb kill-server; adb start-server` if nothing shows up on `adb devices`

Comment: also , add sdk>tools path into environment path variable .

Comment: To list the emulators you've already created, use the command **`android list avd`**.

Comment: Looks like they are deprecating the `android` command's functionality, which is really a shame. All this GUI Android Studio stuff is giving me bad Visual Studio vibes, and the similar names aren't helping matters.

Comment: @trysis What makes you say so?

Comment: Read the page you linked to in your first bullet point. It says the `android` command is no longer supported.

Comment: @trysis That's bad news. How the hell are we supposed to use Android Studio when we don't have a GUI?

Comment: I don't know. All it says is use Android Studio. I would look up blogs, etc. Maybe Google will reverse this tragic ovetsight when they see how many people complain?

Comment: `android create adv` appears [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android). However, looks like you can migrate to [`avdmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager) with a similar syntax.

Comment: @Malcolm - i want to be able to execute command "emulator -avd <emulator_name>" from a script, and get the output. this is for making sure i am getting "INFO: boot completed". but it seems that even though the emulator finishes loading, the command never returns. "Wait until the emulator fully loads, it takes some time" is not an option, as i executing the command from a script and don't want to use hardcoded "sleep".

Comment: @NisimNaim This looks like something you should ask as a separate question.

Comment: @Malcolm i did. simply thought you might know.

Answer (score 396):

List all your emulators:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Run one of the listed emulators with `-avd` flag:

```bash
emulator -avd name-of-your-emulator
```

where the `emulator` executable is under:

```
${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator
```

Or, for newer SDKs, try:

```bash
cd ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
emulator -avd name-of-your-emulator
```

Comment: If you run from a Linux terminal, you must `cd` into the $ANDROID_SDK/tools folder or it will not work.

Comment: Thanks! If you use `emulator` more often why not create an alias: `nano ~/.bashrc` > add `alias emulator='$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator'`, save, `. ~/bashrc` and you're done. (replace `ANDROID_HOME` with the correct variable used or the static path to android folder).

Comment: If the following error is raised: ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib, starting emulator from $ANDROID_HOME/tools is a workaround. https://github.com/decosoftware/deco-ide/issues/289

Comment: If you really don't navigate to the `tools` folder - it really won't work. I got error `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.`. (I'm on Linux, OpenSUSE.) After I navigated to `tools` and then just ran `emulator -avd "{name}"` - then it worked.

Comment: Example for windows: `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools> .\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_2_API_21`

Comment: cd command in windows: `cd %ANDROID_HOME%/emulator`

Answer (score 190):

### I think the best way to reach it via terminal is :

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
```

Or for `Windows`:

```
cd %userProfile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
```

#### To run a certain AVD directly:

```
./emulator -avd {AVD_NAME}
```

#### To list your AVDs use :

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: What is the path for Windows?

Comment: Ah found it: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator

Comment: only one that worked for me, thx - but is there anyway to add it to ur path or smth bc cd'ing there everytime is kinda a hassle

Comment: What @JohnD said - how would I include `./` as part of the `emulator` command into a path/alias?

Comment: In Linux the path for me is `~/Android/Sdk/emulator`.

Comment: for me it's ~Library/Android/sdk/emulator

Comment: Perfect! Working on Mac as well!

Answer (score 30):

Just to add here, whenever you get "error: device offline" means that connection with emulator & adb bridge has been broken due to time taken in emulator startup.

Rather than re-starting emulator at this point try below two commands which stops & start adb bridge again.

> adb kill-server
>
> adb start-server

Comment: In Windows, you may also need to kill the adb.exe task using the Task Manager.

Answer (score 29):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) you can check the options to execute this command via command-line:

```
emulator -avd avd_name [-option [value]] ... [-qemu args]
```

For example, I use it like this below:

```
emulator -avd ICS_ARM -wipe-data -no-boot-anim -cpu-delay 0
```

Comment: Hi germangti, I have the same issue. I am getting "Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: Invalid --abi x86 for the selected target.
". How have you fixed the issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#deprecated `-cpu-delay` is now deprecated

Answer (score 20):

open CMD

1. Open Command Prompt
2. type the path of emulator in my case

> C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools
>   [image]

3. write "emulator -avd emulatorname" in my case

> emulator -avd AdilVD

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Instructions for ***Mac with zsh***:

Open terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T)
Run command
`nano ~/.zshrc`
to edit your profile
Add following lines in the opened file:

`export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="~/Library/Android/Sdk"`

`alias emulator="$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/emulator/emulator"`

Save the file (CTRL+O, CTRL+X)
Source the profile by running command source ~/.zshrc or just log out and log back in
Test by running the command:

`emulator -help` or `emulator -list-avds`
to show your simulator in terminal
and run Android emulator with command:

`emulator -avd <name>`

NOTE: Should be same for bash by replacing .zshrc with .bashrc

Answer (score 14):

If you are strictly trying to run the emulator from the command line try this in OSX.

```
"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator" -avd <NAMEOFDEVICE> -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

You can simplify it by adding an alias to the .bash_profile, and sending it to a background job.

```
alias android='/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator <NAMEOFDEVICE> -netspeed full -netdelay none &'
```

Let Bash know about the changes.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: zsh: no such file or directory: NAMEOFDEVICE

Comment: @Andy you are supposed to replace `NAMEOFDEVICE` with the actual name of the emulator. do a `emulator -list-avds` to get a list of avds that you have in your system.

Answer (score 10):

If you have Git Bash you can open your emulator with a double-click, with some initial setup **(tested in Windows 10 only)**:

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Run `cd ~/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/emulator`
3. Run `./emulator -list-avds` and keep note of the emulator's name. `MY_EMULATOR` for example.
4. Open Notepad and add these two lines (insert your emulator's name instead of `MY_EMULATOR`):

   `cd ~/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/emulator; ./emulator -avd MY_EMULATOR`
5. Save the file somewhere convinient as myfile.**sh**. You can change "myfile" as suits you best, but the extension **.sh** is needed.
6. Open Git Bash at the directory where you stored **myfile.sh** and run `chmod +x myfile.sh`. Remember to put your file's name instead of **myfile**.

And that's it! From now on, everytime you need to start that emulator, just locate your **myfile.sh** and double click on it and wait for your Android emulator to launch!

Answer (score 9):

Open command prompt and go to `<android-Home>\sdk\tools>emulator -avd <AVD_NAME>`

Here `"emulator"` is the command used to open your **Android Virtual Device**.

Answer (score 8):

1. To list all the devices installed: `emulator -list-avds`

This will list all the devices installed inside your Android Studio.

2. To run emulator: `emulator -avd device_name`

For example, if you got `Pixel_3a_API_30_x86` after running the command in option 1, then your command to run emulator will be: `emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86`

Answer (score 6):

The `android create avd` command is deprecated. It's now recommended to use [`avdmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) instead to launch emulators from the command line.

First, create a new emulator if one doesn't already exist:

```
avdmanager create avd --name "MyEmulator" -k "system-images;android-
26;google_apis;x86"
```

This assumes that you already have an X86 system image installed that matches API 26, and has the Google APIs installed.

You can then launch the emulator with `emulator @MyEmulator`.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open CMD
2. To get all Emulator list (C:\Users\DJango\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds)
3. Choose any emulator 
   (C:\Users\DJango\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28)

Answer (score 6):

**Go to the directory where emulator is located**

${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator

**Check emulator list from CLI**

emulator -list-avds

**Run a AVD from the list**

emulator -avd {avd_name}

Answer (score 5):

(Linux)
In you terminal Copy & Paste and changing the three fields in blue

```
/home/YouUser/Folder/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd Android5.1.1

YouUser = user of session in linux
Folder = path of folfer
Android5.1.1 = You version of android in the emulator,for example (Android4.4.2)
```

**you can view the emulators in you folder home
cd /home/Youuser/.android/avd/**

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays asuming you have Android Studio installed (2.2) in my case and just 1 emulator you might use this one liner

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk/ && emulator '@'`emulator -list-avds`
```

If you do this often, make it easier:

```
$ echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk/' >> ~/.profile
```

Add an alias to `~.aliases`

```
alias androidup="emulator '@'`emulator -list-avds`"
```

Recall to `source ~/.profile ~/.aliases` before testing it

Next time just  `$ androidup`

Answer (score 4):

For automation (CI) we did something like below steps:

1. Frist, find SDK's tools location, and store in variable for later use.

   ```bash
   tools=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
   arch="x86_64"
   package="system-images;android-23;google_apis;$arch"
   ```
2. Ensure Android-image's downloaded.

   ```
   $tools/sdkmanager "$package"
   ```
3. Accept the licenses.

   ```
   echo yes | $tools/sdkmanager --licenses
   ```
4. Create AVD.

   ```
   echo no | $tools/avdmanager create avd --force --name MyAVD --abi google_apis/$arch --package "$package"
   ```

   > Says "no" to "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? ..."
5. Launch emulator parallel.

   ```
   $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot -avd MyAVD > /dev/null &
   ```
6. Build APK.

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
7. At last, Android-tests (Instrumented tests) automatically detect and run on Emulator.

   ```
   ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
   ```

   > **Note** that because we launch Emulator parallel, you need to wait until Emulator is ready, and that before Step #7.
   >
   > Maybe count build-time with script, and if build takes less than what Emulator-launch takes, call `sleep`.

Answer (score 3):

list of avd name available on

> .android/avd
>
> /SDK_PATH/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd
>   "AVD_NAME"

Answer (score 3):

In windows, I use this PowerShell script to start it up.

```
$em = $env:USERPROFILE+"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe"; 
Start-Process $em " -avd Nexus_5X_API_24" -WindowStyle Hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows:**

Search **Environment** in Windows Search Bar and choose **"Edit the System Environment Variable"**

In the System Properties window, click on **Environment Variable** and specify the value of the PATH environment variable:

> C:\Users\{**USER**}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.

Now open CMD or Powershell and type:
`emulator -list-avds`
This will show list of all AVDs.
To run specific AVD, type in CMD/Powershell: `emulator -avd {EmulatorName}`

If you have added correct path of the android emulator, AVD will open.

Answer (score 1):

I am late, here but want to share so may be it help some one and me too when ever needed later :) ,
So below is the way to open emulator from command line with one command using bash script.
I am using MX Linux but process is same on all operating systems

1- First Check the installed emulators

```
emulator -list-avds
```

it will result like below

```
emulator -list-avds
Nexus_4_API_28
Pixel_2_API_28
```

2- open any plain text or code editor and create a new file and write as below

```
#!/bin/sh
emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_28
```

Nexus_4_API_28 is the emulator that i want to open you write yours which you got from first step

save this file with .sh extension

3- Then, change the permissions on the file to make it executable:

```
chmod u+x emu.sh
```

4- Now open the emulator just executing this bash script file with following command

```
./emu.sh
```

[image]

Comment: This answer save me and my team lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For one-click (**BATCH** file) launch, this is what I've done:

- got the name of AVD from Android Studio -> Tools -> AVD Manager -> Click on Arrow Down and choose View Details ( for me it's **Pixel_2_API_28**, so change accordingly below)
- create an start.bat file and put the following inside:

> ```
>  c: 
>  cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\ 
>  emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28
> ```

Explanations:

- First line: for me was necessary because I am  launching it from d:
- Second line: for me was not working the tools\emulator
- Third line:
  make sure you change the name of the AVD with yours (here
  **Pixel_2_API_28**)

Using:

- launch start.bat from command line

Answer (score 1):

- easily type this command in cmd.
- replace after `Users\ your user name \`
- if you don't have this file reinstall android studio.
- 

[image: type this command in cmd]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac (and Linux I think), after you have created your AVD, you can make an alias: 
`alias run-android='~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd ${YOUR_AVD_NAME} &'`

**Note**: the execution of the alias will not lock your terminal, if you want that, just remove the last *'&'*.

Run `emulator` it self will give you an error because he expect that, in your current position, you have: `/emulator/qemu/${YOUR_PATFORM}/qemu-system-x86_64'` to start the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple shell script using Zenity that lets you pick which avd you want to run. If you don't have ANDROID_HOME defined, you can just replace that with the full path to emulator.
This would be easy to do with select instead of Zenity also, but I opted for Zenity since I'm running it from the xfce-application menu (though a .desktop-file).

```
#!/bin/sh

opt=$(zenity --title="Choose AVD" --text="Choose which emulator to start" --list \
                   --column="Devices" --separator="\n" `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -list-avds`);

$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd $opt
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the first emulator available:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: I do something similar:
```~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd $(~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds | head -1)```

Answer (score 0):

A launcher script which lists existing AVDs and lets you pick the one you want. Requires `python3` (*at least `v3.4`*) and a valid environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK` pointing to the Android SDK dir.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

android_emulator_dir: Path = Path(os.environ['ANDROID_HOME'] or os.environ['ANDROID_SDK']) / 'emulator'

if android_emulator_dir.exists():
    emulator_dir = android_emulator_dir.absolute()
    print(f'SDK emulator dir: {emulator_dir}', end='\n\n')

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['./emulator', '-list-avds'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=emulator_dir, text=True)
    avds = {idx: avd_name.strip() for idx, avd_name in enumerate(proc.stdout, start=1)}

    print('\n'.join([f'{idx}: {avd_name}' for idx, avd_name in avds.items()]))

    avd_idx = input("\nType AVD index and press Enter... ")
    avd_name = avds.get(int(avd_idx))

    if avd_name:
        subprocess.Popen(['./emulator', '-avd', avd_name, '-no-boot-anim'], cwd=emulator_dir)
    else:
        print('Invalid AVD index')
else:
    print(f'Either $ANDROID_HOME or $ANDROID_SDK must be defined!')
```

#### AppleScript version (MacOS only)

```sh
osascript -e '
set avds to paragraphs of (do shell script "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds")
set avd to (choose from list avds with prompt "Please select an AVD to start" default items "None" OK button name {"Start"} cancel button name {"Cancel"})
do shell script "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd " & avd & " -no-boot-anim > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
'
```

> <sup>The script above can also be run from the `Script Editor.app` or from `Automator.app` (the bit between the single quotes). Also you can use **Script Editor** to save it as a native macos app: select **File** on the menu, press and hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Option) key, select **Save As** and then select **File Format**: *Application*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 what helped me:

1 cd C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

2 list all the available: emulator -list-avds

3 start as NON-GUI mode: emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 -no-window

Answer (score 0):

If you already have emulator and wanted to use that using command just use this 1 line code only

```
cd  C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator | ./emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_32
```

Thanks me Later...

Answer (score 0):

The solution 2023:

Find this on your desktop (with bash, command prompt, etc.)

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
```

Then, run this:

```
emulator -avd <YOUR_AVD_ID>
```

The result will be something like this:

**C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>emulator -avd
Pixel_3a_API_33**

---

To get your Avd Id, you can go to `Virtual Device Manager> Click on [⁝]> View Details`

A list of data will be shown to you, so you can find `AvdId` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd under C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
use emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64
note Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 my emulator name

Answer (score -1):

Starting emulator from command line with dns help

Emulator program location : /Users/{{UserName}}/Library/Android/sdk/tools

1. Check existing avd :-
   emulator -list-avds
2. Start emulator with dns set
   /Users/{{UserName}}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Pixel_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8