# My Android emulator won't launch and there are no errors, any ideas?

Tags: android

When I try to run my application as an Adroid App this is what my console reports:

[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] Performing Hello.World.MyHelloWorld activity launch
[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android_1.5_Emulator'
[2011-10-22 15:21:32 - HelloWorldAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android_1.5_Emulator'

When I open the AVD Manager says that it is valid. When I click start I get a quick loading screen and then it closes and thats it. I have changed the launch action in the configuration. I have deleted and recreated the emulator and the Android project. I am also using Ubuntu 11.10. Does anyone have ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try launching the emulator manually with `adb` and see if an error is reported. You could also try

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Says no command adb found, although i see adb in my platform tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` then `cd ..\tools` then `emulator -avd <avd-name>`. See also [My Android emulator won't launch and there are no errors, any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)