# Playing .apk files in android emulator (Mac console)

Tags: android, macos, file, emulation, apk

I've been searching a lot on how to play a .apk file in an android emulator. Solutions brought me to doing it with a windows console but unfortunately i'm using a mac. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already [try this](http://www.droidsector.com/blog/2010/06/23/easy-way-to-install-apk-files-using-android-sdk-for-mac/)?  That's how I have it setup.  It works well if you are just trying to deploy from clicking on it and don't require the command prompt on the Mac.

**UPDATE**

To actually launch the Android emulator, run this command:

```
./emulator -avd DEVICE_NAME
```

If you are asking how to actually launch (aside from run emulator and isntall apk), check out this very similar post here: [How do I launch the Android emulator from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)

Comment: im having an error running script :( do you know how to fix this. I did exactly what it told

Comment: i managed to fix the error. How do i play it in the emulator ?