# android tablet emulator not starting with 1024 ram size

Tags: android, android-emulator, ram

To increase performance, I want to allocate 1024 MB RAM to a tablet emulator. Problem is that it won't start, i.e. no windows/consoles show up when I click Start in the Virtual Device Manager. If I let the device to its default 256 MB, it starts. How can I fix this?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate with Intel i7-2.2 GHz and 8 GB RAM DDR3. It used to work fine on 32-bit windows.

Comment: Is it an issue of changing the default (i.e., only works on the default setting) or is it only an issue when you set it to a size that's "too big"?  As a quick test, will it work with 512?

Comment: worked with 512, but not with larger RAM

Comment: try to make priority high to the AVD process

Comment: @haythemsouissi still the same. I also got a dialog that the emulator process crashed

Comment: Just had a thought:  if you try to run it via command line, do you get any output back?  There's a how-to on running the emulator from the command line here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't an answer to the particular question you have asked, but it may help with the underlying issue:  you can increase the performance of your emulated device by switching to an x86 version.

The Android emulator has always been painfully slow for me, even on a quad core rig with 8 gigs of RAM, so I started following the [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto) project.  Not long ago, I finally took the plunge into getting it set up, and it was easier than I expected--and it's really, *really* fast.

If you have VirtualBox installed, all you have to do is download eeepc.iso from the project's website (for whichever Android version you prefer), create a VM for it in VirtualBox with however much RAM you want it to have, and boot it up.  Pick VESA mode from the menu, disable mouse integration on the VM, and skip the google account login process.  You'll be good to go.

Then just set up port forwarding for ADB from guest:5555 to localhost:whatever-port-you-choose, and point ADB at localhost:whatever-port-you-choose, and it'll work even better than the ARM emulator that ships with the SDK.

Comment: Works for 2.3 eeepc. I appreciate your answer. Although it isn't 100% on topic, it helps a lot, since it works a lot faster than the standard arm emulators. If I don't get an answer to help me fix my problem with the ARM emulators by the end of the bounty, I'll mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the camera support and I was able to use **1024MB of RAM**.