# Making Apk files run with emulator automatically

Tags: android, command, emulation, apk, adb

I would like to have my Windows Vista Home Premium run my .APK files in the emulator when I click on it. There are ways to do it manually from ADB command line, but I want to make it run on the emulator instantly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you cant directly run it on a click.

you need to store the apk in `android-sdk-windows\tools\`. then keeping the emulator open you can install apk using the install command like this

```
adb install Application.apk
```

i dont think there is any other way to do it.

Comment: would there be a way to make a java program to do that? like right click the app, select always open with apkinstaller.jar, and the jar file runs a script which installs it automatically?

Comment: since all the installing emulator and installing the apk can be done via command line you can actually write a program in java using Runtime class to execute this commands although you might need to check the exact location of the android sdk. it can be done but it would really be an extensive process.
refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line to get an idea.