# I get 'Command Not Found' when I try to run Android Emulator on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, shell, emulation

When I use the [Mac OS X Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29) to navigate to the folder with my Android Emulator and type `emulator`, I get:

> command not found

Here's what happens:

```
$ emulator
-bash: emulator: command not found
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Unless you've added the command to your `PATH` variable you need to specify the path to the binary, i.e. `./emulator` from the directory it's in.

Comment: `export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The [current directory is not normally included in your `$PATH` on a *nix operating system](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default) like OS X; to execute a program in the current directory, precede it with the path to the current directory (`.`):

```
$ ./emulator
```

Comment: OMG this seems to be working! :D So elusive, yet so simple. Thank you!

Comment: which directory am I supposed to be in before I can run `./emulator` command?

Comment: @blackfyre if you are on mac, try this directory: `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools`

Comment: The correct answer would be: edit the `/etc/paths` file to add your `/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator` directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Then the emulator command will work from everywhere, including with build tools, as expected.

Comment: `ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator /usr/local/bin/emulator`

Comment: Tha answer given by Anthony Awuley fixed it for me!

Answer (score 42):

Emulator can be added with Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

To start emulator: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23`

Related question: [How do I launch the Android emulator from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 41):

## solutions

### 1. Symbolic link

> steps

1. create one symbolic link `emulator`

```sh
# soft link
$ ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator /usr/local/bin/emulator
```

2. call the command

```sh
# check all avd
$ emulator -list-avds

$ emulator @avd_name
# OR
$ emulator -avd avd_name
```

[image]

### 2. system environment

1. edit env with vim/vscode

```sh
# zsh
$ vim  ~/.zshrc
# OR
$ code  ~/.zshrc
```

2. add below lines to  the `.zshrc` file

```
# export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/xgqfrms/Library/Android/sdk

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```

3. update config

```sh
# flush update
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

### refs

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: Depending on your android studio version, your path could be a little bit different
`$ ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator /usr/local/bin/emulator`

Answer (score 18):

**These 3 command works for me on VS Code Terminal (Mac Book Pro M1)**

1. `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/' >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. `emulator -list-avds`

Comment: As I had Homebrew installed on my Mac M1, so it worked just by one command in terminal:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`

Comment: I am on Mac M2, the solution works for me :)

Answer (score 5):

typcally i use from terminal :

```
./Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator *some action*
```

Answer (score 4):

Open Android Studio. Click on AVD Manager (the icon with the android and phone) [[example image: AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8uHT.png)]. See the list of emulators. You should see something like *"Install Emulator"* if you don't have any.

Once this is successful, you'll get the ***tools*** folder downloaded to your *~/Library/Android/sdk*

That is the folder you want, because it has the *android* and *emulator* command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed android command line tools using homebrew :

```
brew install --cask android-commandlinetools
```

first make sure that everything is properly installed (so you have no incorrect sdk_root install error when you launch the emulator)

```
# because I installed android-32 and android-34 systems
# —————————————————————————————————————————————————————

sdkmanager "build-tools;32.0.0"
sdkmanager "build-tools;34.0.0"

sdkmanager "platforms;android-32"
sdkmanager "platforms;android-34"

# —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
sdkmanager "platform-tools"
```

and then following xgqfrms's solution, you can edit your ~/.zshrc :

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/opt/homebrew/share/android-commandlinetools"
# instead of : export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/homebrew/share/android-commandlinetools"
# instead of : export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME="/Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.android/avd"
```

you can then add the binaries to your path :

```
ADB_PATH="/opt/homebrew/share/android-commandlinetools/platform-tools/adb"
ANDROID_EMULATOR_PATH="/opt/homebrew/share/android-commandlinetools/emulator/"

export PATH="$ADB_PATH:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_EMULATOR_PATH:$PATH"
```

This should solve the problem