# How to fix Android Eclipse emulator command not found issues on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-virtual-device

This is what happens when I start up a device in the AVD manager using Eclipse:

[image]

How can I overcome this issue so that the device finds those very basic commands? I saw the stackoverflow thread, [*I get 'Command Not Found' when I try to run Android Emulator on Mac OS X*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269274/i-get-command-not-found-when-i-try-to-run-android-emulator-on-mac-os-x), but this is for accessing directly from the command line.

I had this working before but I'm not sure if I screwed up my PATH on Mac and what it should be to find the tools...

Here is my current PATH environment variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Fire up Terminal. Add the result of the command `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: good point. added - thanks!