# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android, emulation

I am getting following  error

```
[2012-06-04 13:23:35 - Newton_Laws] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2012-06-04 13:23:35 - Newton_Laws] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-06-04 13:23:35 - Newton_Laws] Launch canceled!
```

so I am  changing partition size of emulator but it is throwing me error......
please check the screen shot of command prompt...[image]

Comment: did you check the LOGCAT? It says so...

Comment: it should be `emulator -avd` not `emulator avd`

Comment: do you have many applications installed in your emulator ? in that case try removing few of it . I have got this error on real device with less memory and it works if i make some space

Comment: @Alborz in the logcat fle it is not showing as warning

Answer (score 2):

The correct command should be `emulator -avd myAvdName -partition-size 500` (`-avd` instead of `avd`). Note that partition size is in megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong parameters to the **emulator** command (should be -*avd* and not just *avd*.  Please check official documentation at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Also checkout following post for detailed instructions how to run emulator:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974695/200272

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 1):

I've only used it on Linux, not Windows, but I think it should still be:

```
emulator -avd "A" -partition-size 500
```

(You forgot the hyphen before avd.)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed more application's ,then if phone more over's then you will get this error.
uninstall  some apps,then u can install the other applications.same rule apply's for emulator as well as device