# error while opening AVD manager

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm facing  common problems when running the codes to emulator . The console messages are

```
[2013-01-05 19:39:15 - Doodlz] Android Launch!
[2013-01-05 19:39:15 - Doodlz] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-05 19:39:15 - Doodlz] Performing com.deitel.doodlz.Doodlz activity launch
[2013-01-05 19:39:15 - Doodlz] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nex'
[2013-01-05 19:39:15 - Doodlz] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nex'
```

but the emulator was not launching at all even already waited for longer time.

After that, I tried starting the emulator from AVD manager, but the console messages told

```
[2013-01-05 19:39:25 - SDK Manager] Error parsing C:\Users\Dedy\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\Dedy\.android\devices.xml.old
[2013-01-05 19:39:28 - SDK Manager] Error parsing C:\Users\Dedy\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\Dedy\.android\devices.xml.old
```

I couldn't make out these problem. can someone tell me what should I do to troubleshoot these problems?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Have you tried to re-construct the AVD or to create a new latest AVD?

Comment: Yes, I did. but it still unsolved..

Comment: is your ADT is uptodate with your version sdk ?

Comment: yes, I use latest version of ADT..

Comment: have you tested that AVD is getting started manually ??

Answer (score 2):

perform this steps :

1. Delete the old AVD and create new AVD. Might your AVD got corrupt.
2. if doesn't work Restart your eclipse and try again.
3. if doesn't work Go to  `C:\Users\(username)\.android` folder and deleted both the `avd` and `cache` folders. (it may not be necessary to remove both, I didn't check any further). This might help you !!
4. [go to this link and start emulator from command prompt. Check whether there is ADB connection between eclipse and emulator is started or stopped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)
5. If none of them help re-install the sdk and eclipse.

Comment: I suggest, you should try this once and let us know.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I tried these steps, but problems still unsolved.

Comment: what problem your seeing now ?? have you restarted eclipse ?? clean up your code and restart again

Comment: Yes, same problems still occured. also when the emulator launched, no emulator in the list of devices in DDMS.. And when I checked from cmd "adb devices" , none list of devices attached

Comment: re-install everything..  no other options I think