# Error creating AVD after updating ADT, error parsing devices.xml

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I just updated my Android SDK to the latest version as well as my ADT and after that I couldn't create a new AVD.

Here is the error it gives me:

```
[2013-03-07 19:55:07 - SDK Manager] Error parsing C:\Users\sr\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\sr\.android\devices.xml.old
[2013-03-07 19:55:15 - SDK Manager] Error parsing C:\Users\sr\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\sr\.android\devices.xml.old
```

I've reinstalled my eclipse, Android SDK and ADT but still get this error. I am running this on Windows 7.  How can I fix this so I can create a new AVD?

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this issue. here is the procedure.
    just check the old devices.xml from C:\AndroidInstallationDir\android-sdk- 
    windows\tools\lib
    If it contains the few device element.
    Then paste this devices.xml to C:\Users\.android
    restart your eclipse.
    Please try if it works.
Thanks

Comment: I think you can actually use the SDK manager to get rid of system images whihc use devices.xml.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working again by renaming / deleting the devices.xml file; it then recreates it. See also: [error while opening AVD manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110597/error-while-opening-avd-manager)

Comment: thanks Geoff!!! did tat too but no use... solved it issue by reinstalling everything....:(

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps solved my problem

1. Upgrade the Eclipse ADT plugin to latest( I used 22.0.4->22.0.5 )
2. Removed the newly added virtual device in AVD

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here:
[Error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\devices.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402913/error-parsing-c-documents-and-settings-user-android-devices-xml)

and this solved it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404643/891479

With an explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429067/891479

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by editing "devices.xml" and by changing "," to "." in values:

- old entry:
  `<d:diagonal-length>4,30</d:diagonal-length>`
- new entry:
  `<d:diagonal-length>4.30</d:diagonal-length>`
- old entry:
  `<d:xdpi>216,97</d:xdpi>`

  `<d:ydpi>216,97</d:ydpi>`
- new entry:
  `<d:xdpi>216.97</d:xdpi>`

  `<d:ydpi>216.97</d:ydpi>`

Now everything is working fine.