# Error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\devices.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

Since my last update of the Android SDK on Eclipse I have the following error opening Eclipse:

Error: Error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Documents and Settings\.android\devices.xml.old
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'd:layout-devices'.

Someone has ever experienced this problem? I can't find anything on Google and Stackoverflow about this error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself.
This answer put me on the right track:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429067/891479

Copy default `devices.xml` file from
`Sdk_Directory/tools/lib/devices.xml`
to
`Home_Directory/.android/devices.xml`.

`Home_Directory` is the windows user home directory.
Example: `C:\Documents and Settings\smcqueen\.android`

Comment: I suppose a bug in the installation/update setup overwrite the old devices.xml.

Answer (score 5):

delete homedirectory/.android then restart the IDE

SDK will prompt for updates

Answer (score 1):

Delete **.android** folder in your home directory and now run the application from android studio. Error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

go to folder sdk/tools/libs/**devices.xml**  copy this file and paste under your home directory such as C:\User\Computer.android folder