# Android - how to run a local app on an emulator from a command line?

Tags: android, apk, android-virtual-device, nook, nook-tablet

I am trying to run the NOOK emulator.  It is a tablet from Barnes and Noble.

Here is the command I am trying:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-nooksdk-nook-15\skins>emulator-arm -avd BNTV600 -skin NOOKcolor -skindir
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-nookcolor-barnes_and_noble_inc-8\skins
```

I am not certain which directory I need to be in so that the command is recognized. The error I get is this:

```
'emulator-arm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also, how do I tell it which .apk to use? I have more than one apk

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ adb shell am
usage: am [start|instrument]
       am start [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
                [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
                [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> [-e <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_VALUE> ...]
                [-n <COMPONENT>] [-D] [<URI>]
       ...
```

Source : [Instrumentation Testing](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/instrumentation_testing.html).

And you can also check the [documentation of ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) for the various options.

Have a look at this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line).

Comment: just looked through the links you posted. Have to admit I am still confused.  First simple question, for the adb command to work, where should I run this command? I mean, in which directory?

Comment: `<sdk location>/platform-tools/`

Comment: thank you. So the next question is. If I do this command: adb shell am start -n com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity Where in it do I specify which emulator I want to use? My emulator is located in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-nooksdk-nook-15\skins> and I was given the example to run it like this: emulator-arm -avd BNTV600 -skin NOOKcolor -skindir
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-nookcolor-barnes_and_noble_inc-8\skins

Comment: Have a look at this. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#devicestatus I dont think I would be able to explain better than how it is explained here.

Comment: no, I was reading through the links you posted, but could not spend too much time on it so I had to put it off.  I am considering posting a bounty on this question in a few hours when that becomes possible.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh great job! :D Hope I was of any help. :)