# Where to start an Emulator in command line

Tags: command-line, android-emulator

I want to start an **Emulator** in **command line**, but I can't find where to do so.

I have **right-clicked** on various **.exe** files within my **Android** and **Eclipse** folders,

but have never found a window in which to enter **command line** statements.

Where should I be looking?

Comment: I found the answer: Look at  "How to use command prompt and cmd commands"  on     youtube.com/watch?v=foYsmpDrYjY –   Go to the Windows Start Menu, type in "cmd" and the command line screen appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the Answer for you..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974695/3164682)

and [HERE](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-download-and-run-android-emulator-command-line-windows) is the complete reference to create and start emulator in command prompt

more guides are available Google it before asking

Answer (score 0):

**Shift** and **"right click"** on the folder that contains the files that you are addressing in order to get the **command screen** exactly where you need it!!

e.g. for **Windows** users click on **platform-tools** folder for any **adb** commands.

Have a look at http://www.androidcentral.com/android-201-10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know too!