# phonegap emulate android , app not installed , how to initialize android simulator

Tags: android, cordova

I use phonegap build a app,and run `phonegap emulate android`, and I uninstall the app .

The next time I try to `phonegap run android`, It'll still open the same android , which the app uninstalled . That way , I can find the app, I mean how to initialize android simulator and debug the app again?

In one words , how to update the app on the android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

In your command prompt
you can see which devices/emulators connected to your system using

> `adb devices`

you can open avd-manager using

> `android avd`

To start on configure new avd-emulator using `cmd` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974695/3530653)

Answer (score 0):

I would say open up the Android emulator and uninstall the application like you would any Android app - using Android's native uninstall method. Ensure that you don't have differently (re)named versions of your app, and ensure you have them ALL uninstalled.

phonegap run android will run the same code base on Android each and every time, unless you update the code. Once you update the code and type phonegap run android again, it should run the updated code base.

At worst, reset your Android emulator.