# Launch new emulators without the need of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

Going through this documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html) there is the following statement:

> This tool is no longer supported. Instead use Android Studio to create
>   AVDs and create projects, or use sdkmanager to view and install SDK
>   packages from the command line.

So a question was arised. Is there a way to launch those new emulators (possibly via command line) without having to enter Android Studio and then selecting the AVD Manager menu from there?

Comment: This man surely solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974695/6273003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control your Emulator and it's appearance or behavior using below syntax through the command-line.

Here's your emulator `${PATH_OF_YOUR_ANDROID_SDK}/tools/emulator`

```
 emulator -avd <avd_name> [-<option> [<value>]] ... [-<qemu args>]

 emulator -list-avds
```

Launch the emulator:

```
emulator -avd yourEmulatorName
```

For ex : `emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_25`

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) to control the `Emulator` from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

everything you need is here

```
emulator -avd <name>
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   Is there a way to launch the new emulators (possibly via command line) without having to enter Android Studio and then selecting the AVD Manager menu from there?

Yes, you can do it as usual via command line.

For instance,

```
C:\Development\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_25
```