# AVD - crashes when loading any emulated device

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

So I am quite new to Android development but I have Visual Studio 2017 installed and am trying to compile and run the default "Hello World" app just to make sure all of the mechanisms are properly in place for my compiler.

Whenever compiling, the emulated device shows up for a second then goes away. Am I missing something?

[image]

Here are the settings for my emulated phone:

[image]

I did discover that it does work when switching the CPU to ARM instead of x86 but then I get slower performance. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is your dev machine Intel or AMD?

Comment: Check out [instructions to run the emulator from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line) so that you can see any error messages and then go from there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Dev machine is Intel

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When running from command line it says "Incompatible HAX module version 3, requires minimum version 4. No accelerator found." I am currently looking how to update the module

Comment: If you still need help, please edit your question with those details. If you find a solution, feel free to write up an answer as well so that other's can benefit.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your help! I have written up an answer to what I did

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my HAXM version was not up to date. Per Code-Apprentice's advice I tried to launch the loaded devices using command line:

[How do I launch the Android emulator from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line)

This led me to see that there was an error with my HAXM version as it displayed the following error:

```
Incompatible HAX module version 3, requires minimum version 4. No accelerator found.
```

In order to update my HAXM I did the following:

1. I deleted the folder C:\Windows\System32\DRVSTORE\intelhaxm_
2. I deleted the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel
3. From the SDK manager I went to Tools > Extras > Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and installed it.
4. From there I went to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and launched intelhaxm-android.exe and selected uninstall. After uninstalled I launched intelhaxm-android.exe again and installed.

After the above, my x86 emulated device will now launch