# Unable to connect the android studio emulator with vs code

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am unable to connect the android studio emulator with the vs code editor 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPMtA.png)

In image it shows no devices

However when i checked with the flutter doctor command it showed 1 device connected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hajv4.png)

Comment: what is the output of `adb devices`?

Comment: "hello world" at the centre of the screen

Comment: ?? what is the output when you type `adb devices` in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You could try select the emulator manually. 
In your VSCode press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  then type **>Flutter: Launch Emulator** and select an existing emulator or create a new Android Emulator.

Another option would be launching the application through the VSCode terminal. Run **flutter emulators** to get the list of emulators and then **flutter emulators --launch [emulator id]**

```
flutter emulators

flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>
```

To launch a specific device:

```
flutter devices

flutter run -d <device id>
```

Comment: already tried that but did but did not work out

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line) if you are a windows user. you could basically launch emulator from terminal.

Comment: it still didn't work out for me