# Emulator not starting automatically when running react native project in webstrom or VS code terminal

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

Every time if I want to run RN project I want to start an android studio and start the emulator manually and then go to the terminal and run the RN. if i run the project without starting an emulator it's giving me an error.

[error I got when I run the project without starting an emulaotr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlzwr.png)

Answer (score 0):

from my experience this is expected behavior. On Mac, running an iOS project is able to open the built in emulator, but never on Android. The error is just letting you know there are no devices running.

One helpful thing you can do is create a shortcut or terminal command to open your emulator without opening Android Studio, which is kind of a pain to open just to start an emulator. You can do this using something like what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487044/3218158